# Device locale for Hinglish in android

Tags: android, android-resources

To build an android app in Hindi, I have the values folder `values-hi`

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-hi/
           strings.xml
```

**Question:**

- How to have a value folder for `Hinglish` language
- [Here is a link about the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinglish)
- Is it supported by android locale

Answer (score 0):

Android supported languages doesn't include Hinglish

Please see the available languages
https://gist.github.com/lopspower/ce384ef98f3d79e61ec78dc9e512644f

If you're using Android Studio you can:

Right-click a directory on your project > New > Android Resource File
In the Available qualifiers section select Locale and click >>
You will see a list of all Languages and if you choose them you will see Specific Regions for each. You can also type in the list to filter languages

Hinglish is not available on that list!